# Duplicate gridview column in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I use GridView to display my data I want to have each column twice in table. It means when 1 column is full,rest of data put in next column. something like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to separate all values in to two part and added to separate columns on GridView? what is the length of each part?

Comment: yes exactly. for example 5 row in each page.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. One solution would be shaping the data before binding to `GridView`.

Add a class to hold double Fruit:

```
class MyDoubleObject
{
    public string Fruit1 { get; set; }
    public string Color1 { get; set; }
    public string Fruit2 { get; set; }
    public string Color2 { get; set; }
}
```

And transform the data before binding:

```
//Dummy test data
var lstFruits = new List<MyFruit>()
{
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Banana", Color = "Yellow"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Orange", Color = "Orange"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Apple", Color = "Green"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Apple", Color = "Red"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Orange", Color = "Green"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Pear", Color = "Green"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Pear", Color = "Pale"}
};

var myNewList = new List<MyDoubleObject>();
int count = lstFruits.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var newObject = new MyDoubleObject();
    newObject.Fruit1 = lstFruits[i].Fruit;
    newObject.Color1  = lstFruits[i].Color;
    if (count > i + 1)
    {
        newObject.Fruit2 = lstFruits[i+1].Fruit;
        newObject.Color2 = lstFruits[i+1].Color;
    }

    myNewList.Add(newObject);
    i++;
}

GridView1.DataSource = myNewList;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

And the output:

[image]

#### 2. Or you can use Repeater, which is very flexible.

In markup your repeater may look like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFruit" runat="server" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Fruit</th>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Fruit</th>
                <th>Color</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (Container.ItemIndex != 0 && Container.ItemIndex %2==0)? "</tr><tr>": "" %>
        <td><%#Eval("Fruit") %></td>
        <td><%#Eval("Color") %></td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tr></table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code you are binding like this:

```
//Dummy test data
var lstFruits = new List<MyFruit>()
{
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Banana", Color = "Yellow"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Orange", Color = "Orange"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Apple", Color = "Green"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Apple", Color = "Red"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Orange", Color = "Green"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Pear", Color = "Green"},
    new MyFruit {Fruit = "Pear", Color = "Pale"}
};

rptFruit.DataSource = lstFruits;
rptFruit.DataBind();
```